# Raise EvalError and InternalError

Tags: javascript, exception

When i look for type of javascript errors, i found that there are 7 error types as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error). 
I can generate all core five errors such as `SyntaxError`, `ReferenceError`, `RangeError`, `URIError` and `TypeError`.

But, I could not find a way to generate other 2 error types `EvalError` and `InternalError`. How do i generate this? (Or) Is there any example javascript code raise this errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ES5 [specification](https://es5.github.io/#x15.11.6.1):

> **15.11.6.1 EvalError**
>   This exception is not currently used within this specification. This object remains for compatibility with previous editions of this specification.

So I guess this error can't be produced in modern browsers.

Regarding `InternalError`, the page you linked to says:

> InternalError
>   Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when an internal error in the JavaScript engine is thrown. **E.g. "too much recursion"**.

And true enough, running

```
function foo() {
  foo();
}
foo();
```

throws

```
InternalError: too much recursion
```

Comment: I tried above code in Chrome. But i got `RangeError`, not a InternalError

Comment: As you can see in the MDN documentation you linked to, next to the `InternalError` is a warning sign which says *"This API has not been standardized."*. If you see something like this, most likely only Firefox supports / uses this. Look at the [Browser Compatibility section on the `InternalError` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/InternalError#Browser_compatibility), it is only support by Firefox.

Comment: Thanks. Above code throws InternalError in Safari, but not in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Don't know what to say to that other than it throws an `InternalError` for me in Firefox 32.0.3.

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake. You are correct. It is Firefox, not Safari. Extremely sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

You can throw `EvalError` like this

```
throw new EvalError("message");
```

However, `InternalError` is not standardized but in some browsers, you'll be able to *make* that error by doing too much of recursions and `EvalError` is at the brink of extinction as pointed by @FelixKling

Comment: Thanks. `throws` is more straightforward. I want a javascript code that can raise Eval error.

Comment: Heh, vice versa i was finding artificial way to throw this error. Felix's answer helped a lot. And thought you want this also from your description.